# Does harmonic decomposition preserve immersions?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, harmonic-functions

**In a nutshell:** If we start from an immersion, and look at its harmonic decomposition, are the components also immersions?

**Details:**

Let $(M,g)$ be an $n$-dimensional, compact Riemannian manifold with boundary. Assume $f:M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is an immersion **which is not harmonic***. (i.e $df$ is invertible at every point $p \in M$, note I assume $n$ is the dimension of $M$). Let $(\omega,z)$ be the harmonic decomposition of $f$, i.e: $\omega,z:M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying:

(1) $f=\omega+z$

(2) $\omega$ is harmonic ($\Delta_B\omega^i=0,\text{where  } \, \omega^i \, \, \text{ are the components of }  \, \,\omega$ and $\Delta_B$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator)

(3) $\omega|_{\partial M}=f|_{\partial M}$

Is it true $dw$,$dz$ must be invertible?

***Note:** If $f$ is harmonic ($f=\omega,z=0$ then of course $dz$ is non-invertible).

**Update:** As showed by Anthony Carapetis $dz$ can be in general non-invertible on an open subset of $M$. The question whether $d\omega$ can be non-invertible is still open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take $M$ to be a connected domain in $\mathbb R^n$ and the boundary condition to be the standard immersion $\partial M \to \mathbb R^n$ (so that $\omega$ is the inclusion map $M \to \mathbb R^n$).

Then let $\phi$ be a function $M \to \mathbb R$ vanishing on the boundary satisfying $|\nabla \phi| < 1$ and define the deformation $f(x) = x + \phi(x)e_1$. This has differential $Df(v) = v + D_v\phi\ e_1$, so in particular $|Df(v)| \ge |v|(1 - |D_{v/|v|} \phi|) > 0$; i.e. $f$ is an immersion. Additionally we know $\Delta f = \Delta \phi\ e_1$, so we can even arrange for $f$ to be non-harmonic *everywhere* on the interior (take $\phi$ to be a small multiple of the first Dirichlet eigenfunction of $\Delta$).

Since $\omega(x) = x$, we get $z(x) = \phi(x) e_1$, which has 1-dimensional image and is clearly not an immersion.

I imagine you can do a similar "bad" deformation starting from *any* harmonic local diffeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant for the domain and the codomain to be of the same dimension. (i.e $n$ is the same). I will stress this point better in the phrasing of the question.

Comment: Actually I now see that I wrote $df$ should be invertible,... so this was implicitly stated in the question

Comment: @AsafShachar: I believe the mistake was mine - you did state $M$ was $n$-dimensional. Anyway, I've got a new counterexample for you.

Comment: Thanks (I upvoted:). In your example $\omega$ was an immersion. I am still interested to know whether it's possible for $d \omega$ to be non-invertible (on a set of positive measure). Perhaps you can think of an example where this situation occurs? Thanks again.

Comment: @AsafShachar: I think $\omega$ will always be an immersion. Try looking for some literature on the Dirichlet problem for harmonic diffeomorphisms.

Comment: Actually, I'm very unsure. I'm not too familiar with the boundary-value problem so I can't see an easy way to generate a counterexample, but it seems like it might be too much to hope for.

Comment: Thanks. I have now understood my "counter-example" via taking $f$ to be constant on the boundary is nonsense (such an $f$ cannot be an immersion). I have decided it is best to accept your answer (which adresses the issue of invertibility of $dz$) and to open a separate and more focused question about the issue of $d\omega$. If you are interested you can follow-up it here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729011/harmonic-function-with-injective-boundary-conditions-is-an-immersion.

Comment: @AsafShachar: I'm doing some reading  - this question is actually quite relevant to a new direction in my current research, so I'm definitely interested.