# Can the rank of harmonic maps decrease far from the boundary?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, harmonic-functions, singularity, linear-pde

Let $\mathbb D^n$ be the closed unit disk in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $f:\mathbb D^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a **smooth immersion** . ($df$ is everywhere invertible). Let $\omega:\mathbb D^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the harmonic map corresponding to the Dirichlet problem imposed by $f$, i.e. $\omega|_{\partial \mathbb D^n}=f|_{\partial \mathbb D^n}$, and each component of $\omega$ is a harmonic function.

> Does $\text{rank}(d\omega)\ge n-1 $ everywhere on $\mathbb D^n$?

For every $p \in \partial \mathbb D^n  :\, \, \text{rank}(d\omega_p)\ge \text{rank}\big(d(\omega|_{\partial \mathbb D^n})_p\big)= \text{rank}\big(d(f|_{\partial M})_p\big)=n-1$.

Since the rank does not decrease locally, there is an open neighbourhood of $\partial \mathbb D^n$ where $\text{rank}(d\omega)\ge n-1 $.

> **Edit:** In the particular case of dimension $2$, the question is whether $\omega$ has a critical point ($d\omega=0$).

Let us consider the 2$D$ case more closely: Write $f=(f_1,f_2)$ for $f_i:\mathbb D^2 \to \mathbb R$, and similarly $\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2)$. Then $df_i \neq 0$ everywhere on $\mathbb D^2$.  However, this fact alone does not imply that $d\omega_i \neq 0$ on $\mathbb D^2$. A counter example is [given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1741025/104576):

Set $f_i(x,y)=x-2y^2$. Then $\omega_i(x,y)=x^2-y^2+x-1$, and $d\omega_i=(2x+1,-2y)$ is zero at the point $(-\frac{1}{2},0)$.

Of course, to get a counter-example to the current question, we need $d\omega_1,d\omega_2$ to vanish at the same point simultaneously; However we cannot take $f_1=f_2$, since then $f=(f_1,f_2)$ won't be an immersion. I tried tweaking this construction, e.g. by composing one copy of the $f_i$ with some rotation around $(-\frac{1}{2},0)$, but this got me nowhere.

Comment: It can even happen in the case when $n=2$ and $\omega$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Actually, I am interested also in what happens when $M$ is a real-analytic manifold, and $\omega$ is analytic. This paper ( http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02571406) claims that if $\text{rank}(dw) \le k$ on some open subset of $M$, then $\text{rank}(dw) \le k$ on all $M$. In particular, it cannot happen that $\text{rank}(dw) \le n-2$ on an open subset.

Comment: Hey, I know it has been two and a half years ago, but if you have any helpful insight I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: Asaf: I completely forgot what I was thinking. I will think again.

Comment: Now posted on MathOverflow: [Can the rank of harmonic maps decrease far from the boundary?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/320947)